# How to practically calculate confidence interval from the following confidence equation?

Tags: confidence-interval, profile-likelihood

How to use the following equation to calculate the confidence interval:
$$CI_{j,\alpha}(y) = \left\{p | -2PL_j(p) \leq \min_\theta - 2LL(y|\theta) + \Delta(\alpha) \right\}.$$
Here, CI is confidence interval, the log likelihood is evaluated as a function of the values p of a parameter component $\theta_j$. Threshold $\Delta(\alpha)$ corresponds to the confidence level $\alpha$.

Additionally, $$\Delta(\alpha) = icdf(\chi^2, \alpha), $$
or $\alpha$ quantile of a chi squared distribution with one degree of freedom.

Specifically, if I have two (time-series) data sets that are fit simultaneously to a model. How should I calculate $icdf(\chi^2, \alpha)$? I'm sorry if this sounds basic. I don't have much exposure to statistics. Thank you!

The reference is equation (6), (7) and (8) in https://febs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/febs.12276

Comment: For df =1 , $\alpha  = 0.05$, it is 3.84.

Comment: @user158565 Thank you! Since I have two data set, does it mean I have 1 degree of freedom in my $\chi^2$?

Comment: But you fit one model to two datasets. CI is for one parameter, so only $\theta_j$ is fixed in your formula for CI. So df = 1.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @user158565 Does it matter if the two data sets are of different types? Does this affect the degree of freedom?

Comment: Anyway, you fit one model to them. So it is OK.